# Is inheritability of lambdas guaranteed by the standard?

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, standards, final

In the C++ standard, closure types are defined as follows:

> **[expr.prim.lambda.closure]**
>   The type of a lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure
>   object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type, called the **closure
>   type**, whose properties are described below. *[...]*

The standard does not seem to define whether or not the unnamed non-union class type is final. Would a compiler implementing lambdas as final classes be standard compliant, or do we have the guarantee that one can inherit from lambdas?

The question is not whether it is useful or not to inherit from lambdas: it's a given that it is useful. The question is whether the standard provides this guarantee.

Comment: Woa, inheriting from a closure type is something I never considered, for which I cannot find any application right now, but that may actually work. +1

Comment: @Matteo See `std::visit`, where it is cleaner to chain lambdas together (maybe even with other function objects) instead of a generic lambda with an if chain to do type specific things, in my opinion. See also [P0051](https://wg21.link/p0051).

Comment: We can know it's *meant* to be allowed to inherit lambdas from the fact that text in the standard has been rewritten to solve problems when inheriting lambdas, that it was considered to just reject inheriting lambdas, but that it continued to be allowed after a serious use case was presented: [CWG issue 751](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#751). But this doesn't answer whether it's *actually* allowed.

Comment: An unnamed class can't be `final` :)

Comment: @cpplearner Unfortunately, this doesn't mean anything, because it's just a syntactic restriction.

Comment: @Rakete1111: what do you mean?

Comment: @Rakete1111 It does mean something, because the effect of `final` is associated with the syntactic form. :)

Comment: @Vincent It's the grammar that doesn't allow to have a final unnamed class due to the fact that final is not a keyword. `class final` is a class named final.

Comment: @cpplearner Hmm very very interesting. I guess your explanation is plausible. Nice :) thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the closure type must not be final. At least that's my interpretation.

> §8.1.5.1 Closure types [expr.prim.lambda.closure]
>
> An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is
>   described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior
>   of the program other than by changing:
>
> - ... [does not apply]

The standard then doesn't describe the closure type as being final. Making it final would alter the observable behavior ergo the closure type must not be final.

Regarding the observable behavior. Consider this:

```
auto l = []{};
return std::is_final_v<decltype(l)>;
```

Making the closure type final would clearly modify the observable behavior of a valid program.

---

As to a use case, it can actually be a very useful feature:

```
template <class... Fs> struct Overload : Fs ...
{
    using Fs::operator()...;
};

template <class... Fs> Overload(Fs...) -> Overload<Fs...>;

auto test()
{
    Overload f = {[] (int a) { return a * 100; },
                  [] (int a, int b) { return a + b;}};

    return f(1) + f(2, 3); // 105
}
```

See it in action on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/Csq4eu)

---

Thanks to hvd and rakete1111 for the discussions and feedback in the comments.

Comment: The logic would work the other way around: if the standard doesn't prohibit implementations from making the generated type final, implementations are free to do so. Luckily, the standard does appear to prohibit implementations from doing so: [expr.prim.lambda]p3 or [expr.prim.lambda.closure]p2. But I'm not entirely sure about it.

Comment: @hvd Could you cite where the standard prohibit closure types from being final?

Comment: @Vincent The "[...] provided this does not alter the observable behavior of the program other than by changing [...]" bit: making the closure type final would alter the observable behaviour. The thing I'm not entirely sure about is whether unspecified aspects in there and the following paragraphs are meant to be covered by that.

Comment: @hvd Wrong quotes. Observable behavior can only happen if the program is well-formed. [expr.prim.lambda]p2 doesn't apply because `final` is not a *decl-specifier*, and [expr.prim.lambda.closure]p2 is basically lessening the requirements of the as-if rule for lambdas.

Comment: @Rakete1111 1) I don't subscribe to your logic that there is no difference in observable behaviour between an accepted program and a rejected program. 2) Consider a program which prints out `std::is_final_v<T>` if it makes you feel better. 3) The text moved, that's why I provided two alternative locations where the text may be found. 4) That's one interpretation, and why I'm not sure about it.

Comment: @hvd 1) [intro.abstract]p6 disagrees with you 2)  true, but this suffers from the same problem as inheritability, because it says "[...] differently from what is described below [...]", so it can't apply. 3) whoops, I always assume the latest draft, sorry

Comment: @Rakete1111 1) We're in agreement (correct me if I'm wrong) that a rejected program has no observable behaviour, and that an accepted program does. I'm saying that the difference between that is already a difference in observable behaviour. [intro.abstract] doesn't address this. 2) I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean here. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: @hvd oh I see. That interpretation is also valid, sorry. I mean that there is nothing describing final, so there is no way to say whether an implementation is doing it differently or not.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Right, and that gets us back to whether the quote is just loosening the as-if rule, or whether it's also providing stronger requirements in other ways. I can't say you're wrong for taking the former interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of `final` is specified in [[class]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#3):

> If a class is marked with the *class-virt-specifier* `final` and it appears as a *class-or-decltype* in a *base-clause*, the program is ill-formed.

That is, it doesn't matter whether the class is final. It only matters whether the class is **marked** with the  `final` specifier. Since a closure type does not have any declaration in the source file, it is impossible to mark it as `final`, and thus [class]/3 does not apply.

Comment: This is a completely ludicrous interpretation. By the same logic, lambdas aren't callable, because "A function declaration having one of the following *operator-function-ids* as its name declares an *operator function*." doesn't apply to the `operator()` provided by the lambda, as it is not introduced by the *operator-function-ids* syntax construct.

Comment: @hvd Why does it matter whether that sentence apply to the `operator()` of the lambda? That sentence says some declaration declares an operator function. It doesn't say only in this way can an operator function be introduced.

Comment: "Operator function" is in italics. Italics can mean different things depending on context, but in this context, it means it's the definition of the term (see [intro.defs]p3), so it means there is no such thing as an operator function other than a function declared by [see quote].

Comment: @hvd From my knowledge of English, the language does not work in that way.

Comment: Did you read [intro.defs]p3? It doesn't matter whether that's how italics work in ordinary English, it matters that that's how italics work in the C++ standard.

Comment: @hvd You said "by the same logic", but I don't think my logic involves neglection of English grammar. If you think this answer is ludicrous, I think you need a better reason.

Comment: Since we're nitpicking on English and logic, the paragraph you quoted said *"if"* but not *"only if"*, which makes your reasoning incorrect

Comment: @PasserBy Makes sense, but ... https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/1820#issuecomment-345398277